# Site breaks when page contains an unpublishable item

Tags: presentation, datasource

We have just upgraded from 8.2 to 9.3 and some behaviour has changed.

In 8.2, when I make an item unpublishable and publish to cm/cd, the page loads fine without that item.

In 9.3, the page doesn't load and instead gives a datasource not set error.

I assume it's due to some changes in Sitecore's api but can't find where that would be.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check this setting: `<setting name="Publishing.PublishEmptyItems" value="false" />` - was it true in your 8.2 instance and is now false?

Comment: It is false in both my 8.2 and 9.3 instances. I just tried setting it to true and doing a publish but still the exact same behaviour. Item didn't exist in the web DB and the datasource in the final layout was just a guid.